# how to find all faces linked to a specific face

Tags: python, bmesh

I need to find all parts of a mesh which are separated by seams, or which are unconnected sub meshes. As an illustration see the following image:[image]

I need to get the sets of faces for each of the 5 shown mesh areas. How can i do that in a convenient way with Python?

I found this operator:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.select_linked(limit=True)
```

But maybe bmesh could provide a better way to go here ?

Comment: Bmesh module has quite some overhead, standard API is probably faster but may require mode changes. Selection operators are implemented in C, so potentially a lot faster (they can use bmesh walkers), but aren't flexible. What do you want to do with the info later on? Do you want to split meshes based on seems or something like that?

Comment: (i realize your question was posted much earlier)